# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a^\frac{1}{n}-\frac{b^\frac{1}{n}+c^\frac{1}{n}}{2})$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(a^\frac{1}{n}-\frac{b^\frac{1}{n}+c^\frac{1}{n}}{2}\right)
$$

convergent or divergent?

Here, $a,b,c>0$. It is clear that the term tends to $0$. But how do I continue from there?

Comment: Your sum is divergent, take the ratio test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
a^{1/n}=\exp(n^{-1}\log a)=1+\frac{\log a}{n}+\frac{(\log a)^2}{2n^2}+\dots
$$
So we get

- if $a^2\neq bc$, your series is divergent by by comparison with $\sum n^{-1}$.
- If $a^2=bc$, then the series converges by comparison with $\sum n^{-2}$.